# Dataframe - splitting dictionary/map column's keys and assigning values to each of the keys in a row. Pyspark/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe in pyspark which looks like

```
              
CustomerID              counts
3004000304    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES, Home Office' -> 2, 'HOME OFFICE, ACCESSORIES' -> 1, 'OTHER STUFF' -> 2}
3004002756    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES, ACCESSORIES' -> 2}
3004000304    {'ACCESSORIES, OTHER STUFF' -> 2}
```

I want something like this

```
CustomerID              counts
3004000304    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES' -> 2, 'Home Office' -> 2, 'HOME OFFICE' -> 1, 'ACCESSORIES' -> 3, 'OTHER STUFF':4}
3004002756    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES' -> 2, 'ACCESSORIES' -> 2}
```

Basically, I want the values of my dictionary/Map column to be split and assigned to each of the keys.

Either Pyspark or pandas.

For pandas my df looks like this

```
CustomerID              counts
3004000304    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES, Home Office' : 2, 'HOME OFFICE, ACCESSORIES' : 1, 'OTHER STUFF' : 2}
3004002756    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES, ACCESSORIES' : 2}
```

MY APPROACH
I converted the PYSPARK DF to Pandas Df as I don't have much experience with Pyspark and new to it, A direct pyspark help will be much appreciated, else even pandas implementation would be great.

```
f = lambda x: dict(zip(x['Description'], x['Counts']))
df = categories.groupby(level=0).apply(f).to_frame('Counts')
print (df)

df.groupBy("CustomerID").agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_list(
            F.struct("Description", "Counts"))).alias("Description_Counts")
).show(truncate=False)
```

The code is not splitting the keys and assigning values.

Edit

```
{'Customer ID': {8548: '3004000304', 8549: '3004002756'},
 'Desc': {8548: {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 2, 'Home Office' :2, 'ACCESSORIES' : 1, 'OTHER STUFF':2}, 8549: {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 2, 'ACCESSORIES' :2}}}
```

Comment: You need to provide the DataFrame constructor, what you show here doesn't look like a dictionary

Comment: do `df.head().to_dict()` copy the results and post it on your question

Comment: @onyambu I have updated the question, the result I had shown is pyspark df, now I have shared the pandas df too.

Comment: @mozway I have updated the question, the result I had shown is pyspark df, now I have shared the pandas df too

Comment: @onyambu Did what you insisted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only pyspark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = (
    df
    .select('CustomerID', f.explode(f.col('counts')))
    .withColumn('key_separated', f.explode(f.split(f.col('key'), ',')))
    .withColumn('key_separated_trimmed', f.trim(f.col('key_separated')))
    .groupBy('CustomerId', 'key_separated_trimmed')
    .agg(f.sum(f.col('value')).alias('value'))
    .groupBy('CustomerId')
    .agg(f.collect_list(f.col('key_separated_trimmed')).alias('keys'), f.collect_list(f.col('value')).alias('values'))
    .withColumn('counts', f.map_from_arrays(f.col('keys'), f.col('values')))
    .drop('keys', 'values')
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, this seems to work partially.
There are repeated customer id, I have edited the question, the repeated customerid are not summing up.

Comment: @AbhishekPatil Updated the code to fix the sum up.

Answer (score 0):

With the given dictionary:

```
df1 = df.Desc.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(1)
df1['level_1'] = df1.level_1.str.split(', *', regex = True)
df1 = df1.explode('level_1').rename({0:'counts'}, axis=1)
df.join(df1.groupby(df1.index).apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x.set_index('level_1').to_dict())))
 
     Customer ID  ...                                             counts
8548  3004000304  ...  {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 2.0, 'Home Office': 2.0, ...
8549  3004002756  ...      {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 2.0, 'ACCESSORIES': 2.0}

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

where

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer ID': {8548: '3004000304', 8549: '3004002756'},
 'Desc': {8548: {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 2, 'Home Office' :2, 'ACCESSORIES' : 1, 'OTHER STUFF':2}, 8549: {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 2, 'ACCESSORIES' :2}}})
```